# 1 retina pixel spacing between screens in a scrolling UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is there a trick I can use to adjust the spacing between pages at the retina pixel level? The documentation for [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Options_Keys) says the value is measured in points, so I tried specifying 0.5 but it still gave me 2px/1pt spacing.

```
[[UIPageViewController alloc]
 initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
 navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
 options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: @0.5}];
```

Comment: How do you expect that to behave on a non-retina device? I guess there is no way as if now to do that. The point of using points instead of pixels is that it looks the same on both retina and non-retina devices. You cannot draw half a pixel on non-retina devices. ;)

Comment: Some Cocoa APIs allow you to specify half points - I imagine they get rounded up on old devices. In my case I am also not targeting non-retina devices.